# Logic and consistency

Tags: logic

This is a past exam questions, and  I was wondering if my thinking was correct

1. If it is satisfiable, it is consistent
2. We can construct a truth table and verify if there exist a truth value it is satisfiable
3. From the truth table we see it is a contradiction, therefore not satisfiable, therefore not consistent.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Easier than using a truth table: if the first two statements in the set are true, then $A$ is true, and so by *modus ponens* $B$ and $C$ are both true, so the third statement is false.  Therefore there is no assignment of truth values which makes all three statements simultaneously true, and by definition, the set is not consistent.